# Differences when writing code for ARM vs x86?

Tags: python, x86, arm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi.

I wish to start writing code for it using either C or Python.

I know the differences between ARM vs x86 architecture, viz. RISC vs CISC, but what I don't know is that are there any special considerations on the actual code that I would need to write.

If I write my code on my desktop and compile it there, and then take the same code and compile on my Raspberry Pi, will it compile the same or would it break?

Comment: None whatsoever unless you need to write platform specific code or optimize like crazy. Neither of those situations apply to you.

Comment: @closevoters Although you can claim that the question is "too broad" (although I assure you it is not), there's no way in hell this is "primarily *opinion* based". Someone's *opinion* on whether code compiles on both platforms has *nothing* to do with whether it does.

Comment: @Veedrac  I am surprised that I did not vote to close this.  If the question was only *python*, then the answer is fairly clear.  No one bothered to [mention `char`](http://www.arm.linux.org.uk/docs/faqs/signedchar.php) and other issues.  For instance, if performance was an issue to be taken into account, there are dozens of differences in coding style which may compile to better ARM assembler.

Comment: I indicated this question was *unclear what you are asking*, not that it was asking for an opinion. There probably is some code that works only on one or the other. It would be better to ask a question about specific code.

Comment: To avoid memory or performance limits when compiling C or C++, some developers set up a cross compiler.  The code is compiled on their x86 desktop, but the cross compiler is configured to produce object code for the ARM.  I am unfamiliar with the exact details, and recall there is more to it than setting some gcc flags. But it might be worthwhile to learn more about cross compiling.

Comment: The C standard defines 3 classes of compatibility: What the compiled code must do, what is implementation defined (i.e. the implementation must state what the behaviour is), and undefined (the implementation does not have to state what will happen). These problems can be avoided if you are aware of them e.g. `>>` on signed int, may do a signed or unsigned shift (implementation defined). But `/2` always does a signed shift (depending on the quality of the optimiser, it may do it the slow way). **get a good lint tool, if you program in `C`, gcc as a quite good one built in**

Comment: Ask Peter Cordes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write code in python, it will work perfectly fine directly on both your desktop and the raspberry pi.

C, you'll have to recompile but that's about it. There might also be some issues if you start writing data structures to files directly and then using the same files across the different platforms -- you'll typically want to use a portable data format where the data is stored in strings (JSON, XML, or similar...)

Comment: +1, although it may be worth pointing out there _are_ a few specifically implementation-defined areas of C to be aware of (which could affect the behaviour of code, e.g.whether right-shifting a signed int performs an arithmetic or logical shift). There's also a lot of undefined behaviour that happens to work on x86 but not on other platforms, but that doesn't count since it means the code is wrong regardless.

Comment: @notlikethat Well, what you say is true *it means the code is wrong regardless*, that is not really helpful (ie, a complete answer).  Anyone that has spent time with **lint** will know what I mean.  There are key portability differences between an ARM and an x86.  They are a sub-set of **completely** portable code.  That is a plus for a *virtual machine* or *interpreter* like Python.

Comment: @artlessnoise I didn't think it needed much emphasis, since "don't rely on undefined behaviour because your code may not work on another platform" comes a distant third behind "don't rely on undefined behaviour because your code may not work with the next version of your compiler", and "don't rely on undefined behaviour because your code may not work even on your machine, you just haven't seen it fail yet".

Comment: @Notlikethat Yes, that is is also true.  But there are many people who believe that because code has worked on an x86 over many compiler versions, options, builds, etc. that it should work on an ARM (at least the OP has realized this might not be true).  The ARM EABI in concert with the 'C' standard gives some answers such as alignment, etc.  Code that compiles cleanly with all compiler warnings enabled (and passes [static analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) checkers) should have few issues; especially if there is little to no casting.